# Actual math problem re: Number theory regarding divisibility rules

Tags: number-theory

Here is the problem that supposedly has a solution and it is an extra credit problem for my 6th grade godchild. None of us can figure it out :(

Q: For the number ABC, each distinct letter represents a different digit. ABC, CAB, and BCA are all divisible by 6 and 9.
What are the values of A, B, and C

She's allowed to get help with this problem and I'm usually decent at word problems but I now have a headache...Please help!

Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

ABC, CAB, BCA divisible by 6 implies A, B, and C are all even numbers. Divisibilty by 9 implies A+B+C is divisible by 9. That's a start.

Comment: Totally understand!!! We were using 9 instead of 18. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some divisibility rules:

1. If a number is divisible by 9, then the sum of its digits is divisible by 9.
2. If a number is divisible by 2, then its last digit is even.

In particular: $A+B+C$ is divisible by 9, and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all even. Can you find three **distinct** $A,B,C$ that satisfy these properties?

Comment: Now I get it perfectly and can explain to her! (And yes I have solved it too) Perfect. We were using 9 instead of 18 and I knew it had to be even numbers, hence the headache :)

Comment: I have another question involving GCF and LCM...

Comment: Then post another question :)

Comment: I might be able to figure it out myself :) I had to read up on the principle and make sure I understood the silly question. Okay...

Comment: Q: Positive integers a, b, and c satisfy following conditions:      GCF (a,b.c)= 1  GCF (a,b)= 3  GCF (a,c)= 4  GCF (b,c)= 5          What are the values of a,b, and c ?  What is least possible value of LCM (a,b,c)?

Comment: You should post this as another question - I'll answer there, but usually comments should be kept as comments to the answer rather than new questions.

Comment: I think I know the answer already, but if you get credit then I shall post and appreciate knowing that I'm doing this correctly. I do have to explain the concept after :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to solve the problem. If $ABC$, $CAB$, and $BCA$ are all divisible by 6, they're all even and end in an even digit. Therefore $A$, $B$, and $C$ are even. Then, $ABC$, $CAB$, and $BCA$ are even numbers divisible by 9, so they are multiples of 18. The smallest of the three digits must be 2 or 4, since you can't have distinct even digits all at least 6.

The three-digit multiples of 18 that begin with 2 or 4 can be computed by hand: 216, 234, 252, 270, 288, 414, 432, 450, 468, and 486. The only ones made up of three different even digits are 468 and 486, so the only possibilities for $A$, $B$, and $C$ are 4, 6, and 8 in some order. You can check that this solution works by hand.

If three-digit numbers beginning with 0 are allowed, the possibility that the smallest of $A$, $B$, and $C$ is 0 can be ruled out, because the two-digit multiples of 18 all begin with odd digits.

Comment: Thx Steve! I did figure it out once I knew that it could be divisible by 9 and not 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

‘ABC’, when expanded in polynomial form, is $100A + 10B + C$.

Furthermore, $100A + 10B + C = (99A + A) + [9B + B] + C = 9(11A + B) + A + B + C$.

If ‘ABC’ is divisible by $9$, then $9(11A + B) + A + B + C = 9n$ for some integer $n$.

i.e. $A + B + C = 9[n - (11A + B)]$. This further implies $A + B + C$ is divisible by $9$.

If ‘ABC’ is divisible by $6$, then it is divisible by $2$ (and also by $3$).

This means ‘ABC’ is an even number. This further means that C is even.

Similarly, B and A are all even.

The whole question now boils down to

“find $3$ different even integers (each less than $10$) such that their sum is equal to a multiple of $9$.”

Because of the restrictions on A, B, C, the possible candidate(s)

1. cannot be $9$ or $27$ because they are odd.
2. cannot be over $30$ because A, B and C are all less than $10$.

Now the question becomes

“find 3 different even integers (each less than $10$) such that their sum is equal to $18$”.

It is then not that difficult to guess what  the values of A, B and C are.

Note. The question is therefore suitable for kids excluding the analysis in the first paragraph. However, most likely, they have already been told the “secret” of testing whether a number is divisible by 9 or not.

Answer (score 0):

A, B and C are all different even single digit numbers.

A+B+C is divisible by 9.

Only answer is $4,6,8$